# How can I prove that $f(x)=ax-\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}$ is monotone increasing where $a\ge9/8$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

$f(x)=ax-\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}$ is monotone increasing where $a\ge9/8$

I've calculated the first derivative of the function which is ${-\dfrac{3{x}^{2}}{{x}^{2}+1}}+\dfrac{2{x}^{4}}{{\left({x}^{2}+1\right)}^{2}}+a$

and if I simplify it I get $\dfrac{\left(a{-1}\right){x}^{4}+\left(2a{-3}\right){x}^{2}+a}{{\left({x}^{2}+1\right)}^{2}}$

Comment: I'm sure you know what to do with degree-2 polynomials ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative can be written as
$$
f'(x)=a-\frac{3x^2(1+x^2)-x^3\cdot 2x}{(1+x^2)^2}=
\frac{a(1+x^2)^2-3x^2-x^4}{(1+x^2)^2}=
\frac{(a-1)x^4+(2a-3)x^2+a}{(1+x^2)^2}
$$
The positivity of the derivative depends only on the positivity of the numerator.

Let's divide this into cases depending on $a>1$, $a=1$ or $a<1$ and on the sign of $\Delta=(2a-3)^2-4a(a-1)=-8a+9$, the discriminant of $p(t)=(a-1)t^2+(2a-3)t+a$ (when $a\ne1$).

### Case $a>1$, $\Delta\le0$, that is, $a\ge9/8$

The polynomial only assumes positive values, so this case provides for an increasing function. When $a=9/8$ there can be two points where the derivative vanishes, but this doesn't influence the function being strictly increasing.

### Case $a>1$, $\Delta>0$, that is, $1<a<9/8$

The polynomial splits as $p(x^2)=(a-1)(x^2-r)(x^2-s)$, where $r$ and $s$ are the roots of $p(t)$. This will be positive (or assume only finitely many times the value $0$) if and only if both $r$ and $s$ are $\le0$. As $a>1$, this is equivalent to asking that $2a-3\ge0$ and $a\ge0$. But this provides no value of $a$ so that the function is increasing.

### Case $a<1$

In this case the polynomial $p(x^2)$ certainly assumes negative values in some (unbounded) interval, because $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x^2)=-\infty$, so the function is not increasing.

### Case $a=1$

The polynomial $p(x^2)=-x^2+1$ assumes negative values on $(1,\infty)$, so the function is not increasing.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to prove that $f'(x) \ge 0$.
That is equivalent to
$$-\frac{3x^2}{x^2+1}+\frac{2x^4}{(x^2+1)^2}+a \ge 0$$
Since $a \ge \frac{9}{8}$ it suffices to prove
$$-\frac{3x^2}{x^2+1}+\frac{2x^4}{(x^2+1)^2} \ge -\frac{9}{8}$$
Multiplying by $8(x^2+1)^2$, this is equivalent to
$$16x^4-24x^2(x^2+1)+9(x^2+1)^2 \ge 0$$
Now, the LHS can be simplified and we obtain
$$LHS=x^4-6x^2+9=(x^2-3)^2 \ge 0$$
Hence, we have proved $f'(x) \ge 0$ which means that $f$ is indeed increasing.

Answer (score 1):

In your derivative, you can see that only the numerator is important. Besides, it is of the form $A x^4 + B x^2 + C = A (x^2)^2 + B x^2 + C$, so you just have to apply the change of variable $X = x^2$.

The corresponding discriminant is $\Delta = (2a-3)^2 - 4a (a-1) = 9 - 8 a$. When $a \geq 9/8$, the discriminant is negative, which means that the polynom is positive. You have your result!